# Python: Remove list item if it is key for a given value from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a function `h()` that returns a tuple corresponding to the most common element in a list and its value from a dictionary called "`Values`" - so for example, if the most common element in `list1` is a string `"test"` that occurs three times and that corresponds to `Values = {"test":10}`, then `h(list1) = [3,10]`.

When two lists share the same element/frequency, I want to remove the most common element.  Here is what I'm trying:

```
list1.remove([k for k,v in Values.items() if v == h(list1)[1]])
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

How can I remove the key from a list based on its value in the `Values` dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Remove only expects a single element.

```
toremove = {k for k,v in Values.items() if v == h(list1)[1]]}
#either:
for r in toremove:
    list1.remove(r)
#or (less efficient)
list1 = = [i for i in list1 if i not in toremove]
```